# What is the purpose of link elements which create hyperlinks?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I don't understand what is the purpose of [`link`s which create hyperlinks](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/links.html#linkTypes). Why should I write something like `<link rel="author" href="about.html">`, `<link rel="next" href="next.html">` or `<link rel="help" href="help.html">`? This information doesn't appear on webpages. Are they useful only to people who view the source code of a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are *semantic* notations (in this case “sequential links”). They can be used by search engines or other automatic tools to better understand the structure of your website and the relation of the web pages to each other.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#sequential-link-types

These have been around since a long time (HTML 3.2 I think), but have not been widely adopted. The most “famous” of them is certainly `canonical` which can help avoiding “duplicate content” (in terms of SEO).

Here's another nice write-up about the history and the usage of these links.

https://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-link-relations

Comment: I agree, I often see `rel="canonical"` on the Internet, but this value isn't mentioned in the specification. Is it OK?

Comment: Let's say, if [Google advises you](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to use it, you don't say no. ;)